# can't connect to port on android via ethernet adapter

Tags: android

I have an Android app and I'm using Socket to listen on port 33333 on the Android app.
when i use Wifi, i can connect to this port with my laptop(telnet x.x.x.x 33333) without problem.
but when i connect usb-Ethernet adapter and connect it to my laptop:
i can ping my android device with my laptop.but i can not connect to port 33333!!
when i use Terminal Emulator :
i can connect to port 33333 (telnet y.y.y.y 33333)
when i use netstat it show tcp6 on protocol column.
i don;t known what is my problem???
if any body have experience please help me.
this is my code:

```
private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {
    static final int SocketServerPORT = 33333;
    int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //  Socket socket = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
        //  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT,50,deviceAddress);
            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                String messageFromClient = "";
                    if (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
                    messageFromClient = dataInputStream.readUTF();
                }
                count++;
                String data = messageFromClient + "\r";
               Log.i("Data Content", data);
 Toast.makeText(context,"i can listen to port 3333",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               //Do SomeThing Here
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please tell about the -different- ip's you use.

Comment: `but when i connect usb-Ethernet adapter and connect it to my laptop` Sorry dont understand if you connect an adapter to your Android device or your PC.

Comment: Maybe you can connect with telnet but after that you cannot communicate with the server as the server will 'forget' that connection. Please confirm.

Comment: `socket = serverSocket.accept();`. Place that statement before the `while(true)`.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(context,"i can listen to port 3333",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` You cannot display a toast there. It would crash your app. Now didn't it already? Moreover that message should come directly after new ServerSocket(). Where you have it now you could say"A client connected". But NOT in a Toast!

Comment: `(SocketServerPORT,50,deviceAddress);` Please tell what this `50 ` means. And `deviceAddress`? Better use the constructor without a deviceAddress parameter.

Comment: Sorrry. Oversaw something. `socket = serverSocket.accept();
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());` Move all outside the while loop. To above `while(true)`.
 `

Comment: I have usb-ethernet adapter and use OTG to connet it to my android device then i use ethernet cable to connect my android device to my laptop.

Comment: I set ip  to eth0 on android device for example 192.168.9.1/24.and set ip 192.168.9.2/24 on my laptop.Now,i can ping 192.168.9.1(android device) from my laptop.  But i can not telnet to 192.168.9.1 port 33333 from my laptop!!

Comment: That right while loop is not needed.i decrese my  code size and only use socket = serverSocket.accept(); delete other line to easy troubleshooting steps. When i connect with Wifi the connection create without problem. But when i use ethernet adapter as i said before , no connection create!!!!!

Comment: Deviceaddress is a method to determine local address on android device.it determine ip address on eth0

Comment: `I set ip to eth0 on android device` ?? Why would you? You have to do nothing to let such an ethernet adapter work. And dont connect the lan cable to your laptop but to your router. I assume if you use wifi the Android device would connect to a router too. And not to your laptop.

Comment: I connect android device with ethernet adapter to my laptop beacuse i can not use wifi in my project. For step one and test connectivity, i connect android device to laptop with ethernet adapter.i don't need router for step one. So if you have experiance on usb-ethernet on android, i 'll be happy.

Comment: I see no reason why you would not use a router. And you should first on wifi get your code running before you do anything else. And then cable to router. And if you have that running then cable lo laptop.

Comment: As i said , i test it on wifi and it worked.Now i want to test with ethernet adapter.

Comment: My project don't need to router.it work on LAN.